# Performed HARD Reset on Git But Files are still Staged

Tags: linux, git, github, command-line

I am using AWS SageMaker and unbeknownst to me the EC2 created a checkpoint for a .csv file that I added to `.gitignore` due to its size. Therefore, I accidentally added the checkpoint file to be committed.

To remove the file from staging, I performed a hard reset by executing `git reset HEAD --hard`.

I received the following response:

```
HEAD is now at c2770a8 add updates
```

When I executed `git status`, I was informed the following:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Consequently, I submitted `git push origin master` and I encountered the following error:

```
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 61.39 MiB | 5.80 MiB/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: cee6ca9f888bed2a49b7bbd5de9edb1a
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File data/.ipynb_checkpoints/traffic_crashes-checkpoint.csv is 212.62 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/Morgan-Sell/Chicago-Traffic-Risk.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Morgan-Sell/Chicago-Traffic-Risk.git'
```

(1) How come the reset is not clearing my staging?

(2) How do I know what corresponds to c2770a8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that your problem file is already committed.  Adding a file to `.gitignore` doesn't remove it from being committed.  `git reset --hard HEAD` (and that's how you should write it, with options before arguments) also doesn't remove files that are already committed; it resets the working tree and index to the specified commit.  Since the commit already contains the problem file, you haven't changed anything in it.

What you probably want to do is `git reset --soft HEAD^`, assuming the latest commit is the one in which you added the problem file.  That will undo your latest commit and leave all of the files staged.  You can then run `git reset data/.ipynb_checkpoint` to remove any staged files in that directory, and the commit again.

If you added the problem file in an earlier commit, then you'll want to do a `git rebase -i COMMIT^` where `COMMIT` is the commit that added the problem file, and then mark the problem commit as `edit` instead of `pick`, save, and quit your editor.  Then, when Git stops, run `git rm -r --cached data/.ipynb_checkpoints && git commit --amend --no-edit && git rebase --continue` which will remove the file and finish the rebase.

Comment: To add to @bk2204's answer : your staging *is* cleared : you can see that `git status` mentions no file staged for commit.